# “On their part” or “on their parts”?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

> They took credit with no contribution on their part/part**s**.

Should ‘part’ be singular or plural?

Comment: It is “on their part” not parts. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-someone-s-part - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+their+part&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 1):

There is indubitably a logical difficulty in deciding if a plural should be used for this word; this becomes apparent in consideration of the existence of numerous instances where use is made of the variants "[on their individual parts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20their%20individual%20parts%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) (much more frequent) and "[on their individual part](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20their%20individual%20part%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)".

[image]

Usage, as far as what is felt by the users of the language, is clear: whether the subject can be acknowledged as a collective whole or as a multiplicity of individuals, the singular is used.

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+their+part%2Con+their+parts&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

([Christianity Today - Volume 26 - 1982](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Christianity_Today/4Q1UAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22on+their+part%22&dq=%22on+their+part%22&printsec=frontcover)) will so damage a marriage relationship that the partners will find it necessary to divorce. He does not suggest this as the easy way out. It is rather a conclusion drawn by a couple after hard work on their part or on the part of one...

([Creative Power - Hughes Mearns - 1935](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Creative_Power/8cZZAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22on+their+part%22&dq=%22on+their+part%22&printsec=frontcover))  that college sophomores resent even the possession by freshmen. Further, they must know that their best work will be derided and be dubbed inferior or frankly bad; that the slightest headiness on their part will bring unforgettable punishment ;

([Israeli democracy](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Israeli_Democracy/ZdNRAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22on+their+part%22&dq=%22on+their+part%22&printsec=frontcover) )  Still, the proponents of air and armor had to make their cases against great resistance, which stimulated operational thought on their part.

If you intend to make prominent the fact that each individual is responsible for a particular output, then you might consider choosing "on their individual part**s**". Otherwise the regular expression with "part" in the singular is  best.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difficulty in grammar; only in context which sadly, in this case is too clumsy to be useful.

With better wording 'on their part…', would refer to a company, team or other group collectively and 'on their parts…' to the individual members of that group.